# C++ and Detouring

Tags: c++, reverse-engineering, detours

So I started learning c++ the last few days as I wanted to get into a bit of game hacking and reverse engineering. I tried my luck with the basic detour method by just inserting a jmp to my function in my target programs memory which worked fine. However I wanted to start using Microsofts detour library and gave that a go. My only goal right now is to register every time the function is called.

For some reason, my DLL writes the wrong address into memory for the jump and thus crashes the program.

[The jump, the address attached leads to empty memory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DKMOp.png)

It writes to the correct address but just does not jump to the correct place. I am VERY new to c++ so it is probably my mistake but I can not get it to work.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <detours.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>

DWORD AddressOfFunc;
typedef int (__cdecl* func)(int x);

int hookFunc(int x) {
    std::cout << "TRIGGERED!" << std::endl;

    func originalFunc = (func)AddressOfFunc;
    return originalFunc(x);
}


BOOL WINAPI DllMain(HMODULE hModule, DWORD dwReason, LPVOID lpReserved) {
    AddressOfFunc = (DWORD)GetModuleHandleA("Borderlands2.exe") + 0xA18940;
    if (dwReason = DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH) {

        AllocConsole();
        FILE* fp;
        freopen_s(&fp, "CONOUT$", "w", stdout);
        std::cout << "Injected!" << std::endl;

        DetourTransactionBegin();
        DetourUpdateThread(GetCurrentThread());

        DetourAttach((PVOID*)&AddressOfFunc, &hookFunc);
        DetourTransactionCommit();
    }
    else if (dwReason == DLL_PROCESS_DETACH) {
        DetourTransactionBegin();
        DetourUpdateThread(GetCurrentThread());

        DetourDetach(&(LPVOID&)AddressOfFunc, &hookFunc);
        DetourTransactionCommit();
    }
}
```

IdaPro is telling me the function takes an int and return an int, but I have to little experience to be able to verify any of this info so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I've no idea about what you are doing, but from a strictly C++ point of view it should be `DetourAttach((PVOID*)&AddressOfFunc, (PVOID)hookFunc);`.

Comment: And you should check the error code returned from `DetourAttach`.

Comment: Don't post links to photos, rather your code in written

Comment: @john I changed it to (PVOID*) but the result is the same, it writes the jump correctly but to an address in memory that has no instructions.

Comment: No offense, but this is the worst approach to learning C++ 
I've ever seen.

Comment: @Beta all good :) Its not really about learning c++ rather than modifying games for fun. It is just a past time while I am bored at Uni.

Comment: I habe tried changing a dew things but to no avail, it has to be something with detour I guess since it just writes the jump to the empty memory but at the right address

Comment: by the way, leaked NT4 source code has interesting tool in it - "nt4/private/sdktools/autowrap" which makes an existing dll as an input and generates project for dummy dll which mimics real DLL. Such dummy DLL once compiled and loaded by exe, loads real dll in turn and passes through all calls to real dll giving you a chance to analyze input and result of each call. I gave my dummy dlls slightly different name. the only thing you need to do to force exe to use it - patch single byte in an exe, like change kernel32.dll to zernel32.dll. this method does not do any patching on the fly in memory.

Answer (score 0):

As you are using MS Detours, I don't think it's writing the wrong jump address for the jmp.  Your code is correct except there are 2 minor concerns I have

You are using PVOID*, this shouldn't cause any issue but it is redundant.
PVOID is defined as void*, so when you write PVOID* you are actually doing void** which doesn't make sense.

There are some minor syntax differences from the way I typically use MS Detours

Here's what it would look like if I used it:

```cpp
typedef int (__cdecl* tFunc)(int x);
tFunc oFunc = nullptr;

int hkFunc(int x)
{
//stuff
}

oFunc = (tFunc)(DWORD)GetModuleHandleA("Borderlands2.exe") + 0xA18940;
DetourAttach(&(PVOID &)oFunc, hkFunc);
```

If these changes do not fix your issue, I would think the calling convention you're using (cdecl) is wrong.  You can't always trust IDA Pro, you have to manually confirm the calling convention the arguments and the return type sometimes.

Post more info if you need additional help, we would need to see the 10 instructions before and after the call and the first and last 10 instructions of the callee.